# Redirect user for his first connexion

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want new users to be **redirected** to a specific web page only when it's **their first connexion ever**.
I looked up online and on SO, but could not find anything.

Is there any easy way to do it with django ?

So there is what I tried :

**Models.py**

```
 from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField, ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
def verification(request):
#get currently logged in user
user = request.user

#check if the user is the first time
if user.first_visit == True:
    #if this is the first time, change the value for false and redirect it to the place
    user.first_visit = False
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

And in my settings

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'app:verification'
```

But I have an error message

> NoReverseMatch at /users/accounts/signup/
>   'app' is not a registered namespace

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're looking for that but you can add a field to the user models `first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)`

Then check in your view to see if this is user first visit

**I would do it like that**

1.) Create a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) with an additional field

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

2.) settings.py

```
#after logging in, redirect the user to the viewing view.
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'app:verification'
```

3.) views.py

```
def verification(request)
    #get currently logged in user
    user = request.user

    #check if the user is the first time
    if user.first_visit == True:
        #if this is the first time, change the value for false and redirect it to the place
        user.first_visit = False
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:virst_visit_views'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:next_visit_views'))
```

Comment: You meant "first_visit" or is it the way to write it ?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the typo. I improved my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is not very clear and how this function should be added, i understand the concept of using the booleanfield but the view confuse me

Comment: I have an error '''app' is not a registered namespace'' could not go any further